# Ограничение доступа к базе данных с помощью PHP

Tags: php, mysql

На сервере много баз данных *mysql*. К некоторым из них должен быть доступ только в определённые дни.

Существует ли команда *PHP*, которая может включать и отключать доступ к определённым базам данных так, чтобы доступ к этим определённым базам данных в отключенном состоянии был только через "*PHP My Admin*"? Функции, похожие на эти не подходят:

```
<?php
if (date_format(date_create(), 'Y-m-d') == '2015-07-17'
 or date_format(date_create(), 'Y-m-d') == '2015-08-01') {
  die('Увы, нет доступа');
} else {
  mysql_connect(...);
} // То есть например 17 июля или 1 августа, например
```

Comment: А откуда будут идти данные о том, когда можно лазать в некоторую базу, а когда нет?

Comment: Не знаю :D. Думал мне помогут чё-нибудь придумать)

Comment: В любом случае решение далеко не в пару строк. Например, создать таблицу в некоей базе, куда доступ есть всегда (вплоть до той, которая не публикуется в phpmyadmin), со структурой "имя базы(string), разрешено(bool), начало(datetime), конец(datetime)", и запрашивать с текущей датой в эту таблицу по имени базы и интервалу. Если записи есть, брать значение "разрешено" из результата (а если строк в результате не одна и конфликты, придумать как разрешать), иначе говорить "можно". Дальше варианты.

Comment: *Функции, похожие на эти не подходят* — уточните, пожалуйста, по какому критерию они не подходят.

Comment: Для чего это нужно? Где Вы собираетесь это применять и с какой целью?

Answer (score 1):

1. создать дополнительного пользователя. основной будет иметь доступ к phpmyadmin всегда, а второго прописать в свои скрипты что общаются с сервером.
2. создать скрипты с запросами `GRANT ... REVOKE` к базе данных, которые будут лишать второго пользователя привилегий. команды отдавать конечно же под основным пользователем. спрятать эти скрипты куда-то выше папки `www`.
3. запускать эти скрипты по `cron`